# Oracle SELECT statement slow

Tags: sql, oracle, select

I'm on a query.

```
SELECT ttf.default_text
  FROM test_template_field ttf, TEST t
 WHERE ttf.schema_field_id = 2044
--HERE
   AND ttf.test_template_id = t.test_template_id
   AND t.workflow_node_id IN (
          SELECT wn.workflow_node_id
            FROM lims_sys.workflow_node wn, lims_sys.workflow_user wu
           WHERE wn.workflow_id = wu.workflow_id
             AND wn.workflow_node_type_id = 42
             AND wu.u_external_category IN ('M'))
             group by ttf.DEFAULT_TEXT
```

This works fine, and in 8 seconds I get my result back.
But if I add another AND function, it will take 28 Minutes before I get my results back.
Its about this one, his location was "--HERE"

```
AND ttf.default_text NOT IN ('Preparation Microbiology', 'Other', 'Preparation')
```

I don't know why it's slow.. Can someone help?

Comment: Did you take a look at the explain plan for the query with and without that `NOT IN` clause? You will likely find out the reason there. Most probably that clause forces a [full table scan](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Full_table_scan) on the table (that means going through each and every one record on the table). Maybe you need an index on `test_template_field.default_text` ?

Comment: Is there an index on test_template_field.default_text?  How many records are in the table?

Comment: The Explain plan said: there is a full table acces on test_template_field and test. The test table got a HUGE amount of data (over 10000000 records) and the test_template_field got 6980 records.

And there is no Index on test_template_field.default_text.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

- Use [DBMS_STATS](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B28359_01/appdev.111/b28419/d_stats.htm) to update the table statistics that Oracle uses to decide the execution plan
- If this doesn't help, you can use [optimizer hints](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14211/hintsref.htm) in the query to kick the query optimizer's butt into the right direction

Answer (score 0):

Check if you have got indexses on

test_template_field.schema_field_id,
test_template_field.test_template_id,
test.test_template_id,
lims_sys.workflow_node.workflow_id,
wu.u_external_category,
wn.workflow_node_type_id

Also try this query

```
SELECT ttf.default_text
  FROM test_template_field ttf
  JOIN TEST t
    on ttf.test_template_id = t.test_template_id
  JOIN (SELECT wn.workflow_node_id
          FROM lims_sys.workflow_node wn
          JOIN lims_sys.workflow_user wu
            ON wn.workflow_id = wu.workflow_id
           AND wu.u_external_category = 'M'
         WHERE wn.workflow_node_type_id = 42) wni
    on t.workflow_node_id = wni.workflow_node_id
 WHERE ttf.schema_field_id = 2044
      AND ttf.default_text NOT IN ('Preparation Microbiology', 'Other', 'Preparation')
 group by ttf.DEFAULT_TEXT
```

Looks like NOT IN is taking too long ( there is too many rows with ttf.schema_field_id = 2044 )

try this query also

```
SELECT *
  FROM (SELECT ttf.default_text
          FROM test_template_field ttf
          JOIN TEST t
            on ttf.test_template_id = t.test_template_id
          JOIN (SELECT wn.workflow_node_id
                 FROM lims_sys.workflow_node wn
                 JOIN lims_sys.workflow_user wu
                   ON wn.workflow_id = wu.workflow_id
                  AND wu.u_external_category = 'M'
                WHERE wn.workflow_node_type_id = 42) wni
            on t.workflow_node_id = wni.workflow_node_id
         WHERE ttf.schema_field_id = 2044) ss
 WHERE ss.default_text NOT IN
       ('Preparation Microbiology', 'Other', 'Preparation')
 group by ss.DEFAULT_TEXT
```

Comment: The query's performance is the same as mine. Also 8 seconds when i comment the "AND ttf.default_text......". There are indexes at all of them.

Comment: and with ttf.default_text what is the result ?

Comment: over 20 Minutes, like mine

Comment: i could not write newer sql into comment , please try it also

Answer (score 0):

Also you can try EXISTS:

```
SELECT ttf.default_text
  FROM test_template_field ttf, TEST t
 WHERE ttf.schema_field_id = 2044
   AND ttf.test_template_id = t.test_template_id
   AND EXISTS
       (
            SELECT 1
              FROM lims_sys.workflow_node wn, lims_sys.workflow_user wu
             WHERE wn.workflow_id = wu.workflow_id
               AND wn.workflow_node_type_id = 42
               AND wu.u_external_category = 'M'
               AND t.workflow_node_id  = wn.workflow_node_id)
 GROUP BY ttf.default_text
;
```