# Bitmap Join Index

Tags: oracle, oracle11g, oracle10g, data-warehouse

When creating a BJI between fact table and dimension

```
CREATE BITMAP INDEX IDX_BITJ ON fact(dimension.city) 
FROM fact, dimension 
WHERE fact.id_customer = dimension.id_customer;
```

and then query:

```
select sum(a.count) from fact a, dimension b 
where a.id_customer = b.id_customer and b.city = 'London';
```

The explain plan will alway use a full scan on the tables ...
can anyone explain me why? shouldnt the bitmap index get used?

Comment: Just because you have an index, Oracle's query optimizer will not always choose to use it. See my answer at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19836211/oracle-select-statement-slow for some hints.

Comment: How many customers are there in your fact table? How many of these customers live in London? (I presume it's live though it could also be something like "bought" in London).

Comment: 11 million rows in fact tbl, about 700.000 are from london

Comment: I presume `id_custumer` is a typo.

Comment: I presume statistics are up-to-date. Does it work for a different city with fewer customers?

Comment: you are right, BJI is used on cities with a lower count

Comment: How many rows does Oracle *think* it's going to get? ie what does the execution plan say?

Comment: where can I see that?

Comment: I usually use autotrace in SQL*Plus with `set autotrace on` or similar.